# How to convert pdf pages into images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have one problem, that is how to convert pdf pages into images natively. I tried this link https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF but want to know do we have any default functions in Objective c

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: can you please attached sample code which you try.

Comment: Please explain in details.

Comment: Hey Prabakaran, I have used this https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF but want to know do we have any default functions in Objective c

Comment: Please mentioned above point also in your question. Then only you will get exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your assets are in pdf format then you don't need to convert it to images.
You just add these pdf file in asset and refer to these file as we do for .png/jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to use this library. You must make sure you have path of `PDF`, convert into URL, then simply add on `UIImage` on that URL.

Import the Library File:
[Download from here](https://github.com/a2/FoodJournal-iOS/tree/master/Pods/UIImage%2BPDF/UIImage%2BPDF)

```
import "UIImage+PDF.h"

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath];

UIImage *img = [ UIImage imageWithPDFURL:url atSize:CGSizeMake( 60, 60 ) atPage:1 ];
```